# Consultar uma tabela inserindo "" em campo de número no Oracle

Tags: oracle

Essa query precisa trazer o campo número do endereço entre ""

```
SELECT a.ds_endereco, 
       a.nr_endereco, 
       a.nm_bairro, 
       c.nm_cidade, 
       c.cd_uf, 
       a.nr_cep, 
       A.nr_fone, 
       a.nr_celular 
FROM   paciente A, 
       cidade c 
WHERE  a.cd_cidade = c.cd_cidade 
       AND a.tp_situacao = 'N' 
       AND a.cd_paciente <> 1 
ORDER  BY 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT a.ds_endereco,
       '"' || TO_CHAR(a.nr_endereco) || '"',
       a.nm_bairro,
       c.nm_cidade,
       c.cd_uf,
       a.nr_cep,
       A.nr_fone,
       a.nr_celular
FROM   paciente A,
       cidade c
WHERE  a.cd_cidade = c.cd_cidade
       AND a.tp_situacao = 'N'
       AND a.cd_paciente <> 1
ORDER  BY 1
```

> [`|| Operator`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/concat2.php)
>
> The `Oracle/PLSQL ||` operator allows you to concatenate 2 or more `strings` together.

Ou em tradução livre:

> O operador `||` do `Oracle/PLSQL` permite que você concatene 2 ou mais `strings` juntas.

---

> [`TO_CHAR`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php)
>
> The `Oracle/PLSQL TO_CHAR` function converts a `number` or `date` to a `string`.

Em tradução livre:

> A função `TO_CHAR` do `Oracle/PLSQL` converte um `number` ou `date` para uma `string`.

Comment: Eu consegui quando adicionei dois ||